# Primefaces p:pickList and the required attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, picklist

**EDIT:**
I found the explanation (played around with f:event) and saw that PF has the behaviour I was assuming, namely that the backing bean values of the PF framework themselves are not updated, because the validation phase failed (therefore skipping the update model values phase and directly go to render phase) leaving the source/target list as they were before.

I have the following code:

```
           <p:pickList
            id="parentpicklist"
            value="#{manager.parent}"
            var="entity"
            itemValue="#{entity}"
            labelDisplay="true"
            required="true"
            rendered="#{not empty manager.parent.source or not empty manager.parent.target}">
```

At the end of the page I have a p:commandButton like this:

```
         <p:commandButton
          action="#{manager.save}"
          value="#{messages.saveLabel}"
          title="#{messages.saveHint}"
          update="edit-extract" <!-- the picklist resides inside of this component -->
          rendered="#{manager.editMode}">
```

**The scenario:**
On the page is this picklist and it has its source and target list populated with values, i.e., both are not empty.
**Now the problem is the following:** When I remove *all* items from the target list and press 'save', then the validation fails and it says: validation required. So far so good.

THE PROBLEM: It does not *only* show that the validation failed, but it updates the `picklist` with its initial values when loading the page.
Is this PF standard behavior?

Because `p:commandButton` has as default `process="@form"` (that is why it is validating the `picklist` which is inside the form). I tried out several stuff to set the **targetlist** content by my own, e.g., with the `onTransfer` event.
BUT it does not update the target list --> It looks like the validation fails and the **targetlist** does not get updated (jsf validation fails and goes directly to the `renderResponse` phase, i.e., the model values are not updated) and therefore the old resp. initial values are loaded.

Best regards,

ProgrammingIsAwsome

Comment: What do you mean `It does not only show that the validation failed, but it updates the picklist with its initial values when loading the page.` Do yo mean Source list updated ? You already mentioned target list empty. How could source updates?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: e.g. because the list is serverside reinitialized due to a wrong scope

Comment: @Kukeltje Agree its a server side but my question with SO user how it updated its due to wrong scope or some thing else wrong in the code?

Comment: Try it with a requestscoped bean… even…

Comment: What I mean with initial values:
Initial state: source --> 2 items / target --> 1 item

What I want: move the one item from target to source and press enter with the following result: display error message BUT source --> 3 items / target --> 0 items

Current status resp. result: display error message AND source --> 2 items / target --> 1 item (initial values)

Comment: Also there is no redirection or whatsoever. I also just made a button just to update the picklist (and nothing else) and still the same behaviour.
Also I checked the JSF phases. It goes from the PROCESS validation phase to the RENDER response phase (what is expected when validation fails), but the target list is not updated --> my suggestion is that PF does if a validation error occurs, not update the model values, e.g., the target list

Btw.: The target and source lists are not my properties in the backing bean, they are handled by PF.

Comment: That might be the problem because the target and source lists are not updated (backing bean values of PF for their picklist)?